# Cannot manipulate select tag with JavaScript after opening it

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I run into weird behavior of Internet Explorer 8 when manipulating `<select>` tags with JavaScript.

Say I want to add an `<option>` to a `<select>`, than in jQuery I can use something like `$("select").prepend(myOption)`. But if the `<select>` element is created with JavaScript *AND* the user has opened the select, this doesn't work and Internet Explorer (8) doesn't show the new option. In Firefox this works just fine.

An example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function prependOption(select) {
            $("select").each(function(i, element) {
                var option = $('<option value="abc">xyz</option>');
                $(element).prepend(option);
            });
        }
        $(function() {
            var container = $("#container");
            container.append($("select.prototype").clone());
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>  
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="prependOption(this)" /><br />
<div id="container">
    <select class="prototype">
        <option>Lorem ipsum</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you open the page, you should see two select boxes - one normal and one created using jQuery's `clone()`. If you click the button, an option is added to both of them. Now if you click and open both select boxes and click the button again, a new option is added only to the first select box.

Any idea how to work around this buggy behavior? I need to add options to a `<select>` created with JavaScript.

Comment: Where the error is exactly occurring I'm not sure... however IE9 and below are well known to have issues with the .innerHTML property. http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/08/bug-274-dom-methods-on-select-lists.html as well as issues with focusing events http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2009/02/bug-487-onclickonfocus-bugs-on-select.html If under the covers jQuery is trying to manipulate these without overcoming the IE bugs it may have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to avoid `clone()` - apparently it doesn't work properly in Internet Explorer 8.

```
var select = $('<select></select>');
select.append($("select.prototype option").clone());
container.append(select);
```

So instead of cloning the  `<select>`, I create a new one and only clone its options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this    :

```
new Object($("select.prototype"))
```

Comment: If you mean in the container.append() call, then `new Object($("select.prototype"))` nor `new Object($("select.prototype").clone())` doesn't help